# Altering the table name in Procedure using execute immediate

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Hope you are doing well....

I want to alter a table name  in Procedure using execute immediate.
But the twist here is i want to append the sysdate (format: YYYYMMDD) to the existing table name.

ex: Table_name : Sales
Rename should be : sales_20170907

Please help me ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
execute immediate 'rename sales to sales_' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: Missing one Y in date format. Can't edit less than 6 characters :|

Comment: @Dessma Thanks, fixed